Fill in lune of Coxeter Complex
Ultimately I'm trying to draw the tiling of a sphere with triangle group (2,3,4) (i.e., Coxeter complex B3) and shade in various lunes.  I figured out how to draw the tiling of the sphere using the blocsphere package (as shown with code below).  But I can't for the life of me figure out how to now fill the area between two great circles using blocsphere.  Any help with trying to code both the Coxeter complex as well as a lune would be appreciated  Here's the code that I have for the tiling of the sphere:
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{blochsphere}
\pgfsetlayers{back,main,front}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \begin{blochsphere}[radius=1.5 cm,tilt=25,rotation=-20,nested=true]
            % The next line is automatically included when not nesting
            % but needs to be here when nesting
            \drawBall

            \drawBallGrid[style={draw,opacity=1}]{360}{45}

            \drawGreatCircle{45}{0}%[style={dashed}]
            \drawGreatCircle{-45}{0}%[style={dashed}]
            \drawGreatCircle{45}{-90}
            \drawGreatCircle{-45}{-90}
            
        \end{blochsphere}

    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}

And here is what I'm trying to draw at the end of the day:


Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

@José Carlos Santos:  Hi!  I just added the image from the compiled code.  Is this what you're looking for?  It's just the B_3 Coxeter complex.  I couldn't figure out how to start drawing lunes using the blochsphere package.

Did you bother to click the link from my previous comment?

You really need to complete your code. As it is now, your question will most likely be closed. I do not know, but I doubt that it is possible to use the very simple package to fill anything. You would need to use TikZ and then there would be no advantage left of using blochsphere at all.

@José Carlos Santos:  I did look at the link you provided.  I'm still not sure what you are looking for.

@hpekristiansen:  I don't know how to complete my code.  That's what I'm asking.  I don't care if the end result uses blochsphere or not (as stated).  Using blochsphere was the only way that I could figure out how to get the Coxeter complex.  I'm hoping someone can figure out how to both draw the Coxeter complex and fill in a lune.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz:  Thank you!!!  I now understand what the others were asking.  I really appreciate it!

Maybe this is not the most straight-forward way, but with the use of the fillbetween library from the pgfplots package you could do like this:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{blochsphere}
\pgfsetlayers{back, main, front}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{blochsphere}[radius=1.5cm, tilt=25, rotation=-20, nested=true]
        \drawBall

        \drawBallGrid[style={draw}]{360}{45}

        \drawGreatCircle{45}{0}
        \drawGreatCircle{-45}{0}
        \drawGreatCircle{45}{-90}
        \drawGreatCircle{-45}{-90}

        \drawGreatCircle[style={red, name path global=A}]{90}{135}
        s\drawGreatCircle[style={red, name path global=B}]{90}{180}
    \end{blochsphere}

    \fill[cyan, opacity=0.5,
        intersection segments={of=A and B, sequence={L1 -- R1[reverse]}}] to[bend right=5] cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


(The bottom part is not super exact, but I opted for this solution instead of calculating the intersections of the large circles with the circumcircle.)


Thank you very much!!!!!
